# Getting child process exited abnormally error on git commit

Tags: git

I frequently get an error message while performing commits from the GIT GUI, which says:

```sh
child process exited abnormally
child process exited abnormally
    while executing
"close $fd_ot"
    (procedure "commit_committree" line 24)
    invoked from within
"commit_committree file228463e6830 6bab594ce....2a2487cd70bdb32 .git/GITGUI_EDITMSG"
```

Comment: Which version of Git are you using? On which OS?

Comment: I'm using 2.33.1 on windows.

Comment: Would the issue persists with 2.35.1.2?

Comment: I'm using git GUI since 2011 (Windows bash) and I've always faced this message, occurring at times. Killing and relaunching bash doesn't help. I then normally do git commit -m ".... (the copied message)" and that seems to turn git GUI into a "normal" state again, for several days or weeks.

Comment: After a few days, the git commits work fine automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Typically i got this issue while trying to commit in git gui - while on a active cherry-pick, thus instead of trying to commit - just close the cherry-pick using the command -

```
git cherry-pick continue
```

//& then as usual -

```
git push origin head
```

thus it resolves